# how to get price in high to low order

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-order-by

How to get price in high to low order, Please help me 
Given below my query....

i was define price datatype as float

```
select * from product_tb where sub_id='"+bl.sub_id+"' order by price desc
```

But by this query my out put is:

```
9999,
999,
9980,
990,
99,
99,
950,
95,
900,
799,
700,
695,
695,
6595,
6592,
600,
595,
```

And i want to my output like:

```
9999,9980,6595,6592,999,990,950,900,799,700,695,600,595,99,99,95
```

suggeste me proper query and method for this scenario.  thank you

Comment: what is the type of "price"

Comment: That doesn't look like float and you shouldn't use float for currency.

Comment: Are you **sure** that's a `float`? It doesn't look that way. You should consider using `money` or `smallmoney` to store currency values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ordering a "text" field, the result goes alphabetically. You need to cast as Int your price field:

```
select * from product_tb where sub_id='"+bl.sub_id+"' order by CAST(price AS INT) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 select * from product_tb where sub_id='"+bl.sub_id+"' order by Convert(float,price) desc
```

and if it worked, you should conclude that price is not declared as float.